# How to select defense plays based on suspected offense plays?

Tags: madden-21

I was playing madden 08 on a wii with a friend, and I loved how defensive plays were chosen.  They would give a bunch of basic offensive play types, like "Short Pass, Medium Pass, Deep Pass, Inside Run" etc.  When you selected these, you would be given a list of defensive plays that counteract those offensive plays.  That way I could guess my opponents next move, and then select a corresponding play easily.

In madden 21, I can select plays based on blitzes, man coverage, zone, or formation etc, but I'm not sure how I can select based on offensive play.  Does madden 21 have a way to do this?

If not, what categories of plays should I select for the common play types (there are a lot of options and I'm new to madden)

Thanks, if this was not clear please comment and I'll explain further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This option is not available in Madden 21. But the developers added it in Madden 22 (see picture)

[image]

Comment: good to know, thnx